# 100% CPU, stuck on CreateDelegate and CerHashtable`2.get_Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, windbg

I have a .NET 3.5 website that occasionally hangs and spikes to 100% CPU.  Running a dump through WinDbg shows that about half of my threads are sitting at

```
System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].get_Item(System.__Canon)
```

and the other half are sitting at

```
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(System.Type)
```

they are all in the middle of LINQ-to-SQL queries. Does anybody know what could be going on here?  The DB appears to remain responsive, at least from SSMS while the problem is going on.

If anyone needs more information to go on, let me know.

**Edit:**

There are 22 threads.  (and I was generalizing when I said half)  This is output of !threads

```
ThreadCount: 23
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 22
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 1
Hosted Runtime: no
                                              PreEmptive                                                Lock
       ID OSID        ThreadOBJ     State   GC     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
   7    1 19a0 00000000022c7710      8220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 Ukn
  27    2 1fa0 0000000005591f90      b220 Enabled  00000001a0425058:00000001a04266c0 00000000022a2940     0 MTA (Finalizer)
  29    3 4824 0000000006550450   380b220 Enabled  000000012213cf18:000000012213dec0 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  30    4 40c8 00000000061378c0   380b220 Enabled  00000001c1f84c38:00000001c1f860f0 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  31    5 2a54 0000000006138770   180b220 Disabled 0000000101e3c858:0000000101e3db00 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  32    6 1984 000000000613c940   180b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000067500a0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker) System.ObjectDisposedException (000000017fffe458)
  33    7 18d8 000000000613eb80   380b220 Enabled  00000001820c3a30:00000001820c3c90 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  34    8 31f4 0000000006141d10   380b220 Enabled  0000000122147048:0000000122147ec0 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  35    9 5fe4 00000000061427c0   180b220 Enabled  00000001e1ffbdc8:00000001e1ffc190 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  36    a 3768 0000000006143270   180b220 Enabled  00000001e200add0:00000001e200c190 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  37    b 1820 000000000670fa10    80a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  38    c 1220 000000000673e160      1220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 Ukn
  39    d 507c 0000000008c1f9b0   180b220 Enabled  0000000101e392d0:0000000101e39b00 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  14    e 651c 000000000a507000   880a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  40    f 14a0 000000000ab0a850   380b220 Enabled  00000001a15886c0:00000001a158a638 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   10    0 000000000bd7c7b0      9820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 MTA
  42   11 48d8 000000000c00c120   380b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000067500a0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
   3   12 6180 000000000c00c6f0       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000022a2940     0 Ukn
  43   13 3798 000000000c00d290   180b220 Enabled  00000001420f9730:00000001420f9828 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  45   14 1be8 000000001184f150   180b220 Enabled  00000001c1f880e0:00000001c1f880f0 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  48   15 13ec 000000001184f720   200b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000067500a0     1 MTA
  49   17 3bac 00000000198f1b20   180b220 Enabled  0000000182059020:0000000182059c90 00000000067500a0     2 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  50   16 4670 00000000197b6b00   380b220 Enabled  0000000162040fd0:0000000162042658 00000000067500a0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
```

and this is the lengthy result of !EEStack   (posted on pastebin since it wouldn't fit in this post)

http://pastebin.com/qcF4jX1g

I am using SQL 2005 standard

**EDIT:**

Here is the result is !syncblk, which shows the "CerHashtable" as the owner, although all threads on CerHashtable appear to be waiting for a lock?

```
Index         SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info          SyncBlock Owner
  148 000000000e4ec1f8           12         0 0000000000000000     none    000000017fe48560 System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2[[System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib],[System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib]]
        Waiting threads:*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for NewRelic.Profiler.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for NewRelic.Profiler.dll - 
 29 30 33 34 40 50
-----------------------------
Total           252
CCW             3
RCW             5
ComClassFactory 0
Free            81
```

Comment: Could you please post your stack traces?

Comment: Have you checked if you are also using non thread safe collections? Web apps are multi threading by default, so you must lock them manually or switch to concurrent ones.

Comment: Are you using SQL Express or SQL Standard?

Comment: Half of your  threads - how many threads?

Comment: edited the question.  if you need anything else let me know

Comment: use ETW/WPRUI next time to analyze :https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: Would you mind running [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx)'s `!dlk` for me? There's also an ObjectDisposedException which doesn't sound great.

Comment: @ThomasWeller : Examining SyncBlocks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLockSlim instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
Scanning for threads waiting on SyncBlocks...
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLocksSlim locks...
Scanning for threads waiting on CriticalSections...
No deadlocks detected.
....

Comment: @ThomasWeller : also, the ObjectDisposedException appears to be on a thread that is just monitoring performance (newRelic).  I installed the performance monitor originally just to try to help locate the problem.  So I don't think it is related.

Comment: @magicandre1981 : unfortunately, this server is plain old windows server 2008 and does not support the windows performance toolkit.   although that should be changing soon, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @zespri - Do you see anything from the stack traces?

Comment: Nope. I was hoping that it might relate to how Linq2Sql is used somehow, but it does not look it does.

Comment: Check the msdn documentation to ensure all of your methods are thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

> Linq-To-Sql was discontinued by Microsoft.

**They recommend using Entity Framework.**

It would not be a huge overhaul since you linq code us still valid.
You just need to recreate you data model.

For .Net 3.5 you can use EF v1.

Try to download Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22
It should include The First version of Entity Framework (EFv1) as stated on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework.